# Atributo "wrap" da tag textarea

Tags: html, html5, textarea

Qual é a utilidade do atributo `wrap` da tag `textarea`?

Qual a diferença entre seus valores `soft, hard, off`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apenas pra complementar a outra resposta, conforme a documentação do [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)

Indica como o deve funcionar a quebra do texto no `<textarea>`

- **hard**: O navegador automaticamente insere quebras de linhas (CR+LF) no momento que o formulário é submetido de modo que cada linha não ultrapasse o limite da largura do campo, o atributo `cols` deve ser especifico.
- **soft**: (este é o calor padrão se omitido `wrap=""`) O navegador garante que todas as quebras de linha no valor consistem em um par (CR+LF), mas não insira quaisquer quebras de linha adicionais quando o formulário é submetido.

Conforme o [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/textarea.html#textarea.attrs.wrap.hard) são dos valores (soft e hard) são novas funcionalidades HTML5, mesmo que funciona-se em alguns navegadores antigos, talvez não fosse *standard*.

> Nota:
>
> - *Carriage return* (CR, 0x0D, \r) move o cursor para o começo da linha sem avançar para a próxima linha. Esse caractere é usado como um caractere de nova linha nos sistemas operacionais Commodore e Early Machintosh (OS-9 e mais antigos).
> - *Line feed* (LF, 0x0A, \n) move o cursor para a próxima linha sem retornar para o começo da linha. Esse caractere é usado como um caractere de nova linha nos sistemas baseados em UNIX (Linux, MAC OSX, etc)
>
> Fonte: http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/2856874215F6134A862576C400554081

Comment: É importante citar que ele quebra só o valor ao submeter.

Answer (score 3):

O atributo wrap especifica como o texto no elemento textarea é para ser ajustado quando um formulário é submetido.

**Soft**: O texto no elemento não é ajustado quando é submetido em um formulário. Esse é o valor padrão.

**Hard**: O texto no elemento é ajustado (contendo novas linhas) quando é submetido em um formulário. Quando `hard` é utilizado, o atributo `cols` deve ser especificado.

**EDIT**

Isto torna uma ótima maneira de dar aos usuários um exemplo ou a descrição de como proceder para preencher o campo área de texto. Algo como, "Por favor, limite a sua resposta a 100 caracteres," seria uma descrição ideal.

Referências:

[HTML  wrap Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_wrap.asp)

[Tizag - HTML - textareas](http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmltextarea.php)

Comment: Este é o básico da documentação, você sabe me dizer se há alguma vantagem ou em qual momento é aconselhável utilizar um ou outro ?

Comment: Boa pergunta Gabriel, também gostaria de saber.

Comment: Editei a resposta quanto a utilização e adicionei uma nova referência.

Comment: Não entendi porque diz que é `o novo atributo para a tag <textarea> no HTML 5`. É um atributo dos mais antigos do HTML.

Comment: Traduzi do W3Schools essa informação

Comment: @DanielOmine acho que não era padronizado, conforme todas fontes que encontrei é html5, veja: https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/textarea.html#textarea.attrs.wrap.hard

Comment: Verdade! Para o elemento textarea é um recurso oficialmente novo. Já era possivel usar antes no html4 mas não era oficialmente suportado.